# How Do I Properly Make An Image Respond To A Browser's Adjustment?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I have a simple question: How do I make an image properly respond to the viewport?

I have a 400 pixel (400px) wide and tall image, and I'd like it to become only 90% of the viewport width (90vw) when the browser is resized, so here is my current code:

```
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  img {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
  }
}
```

But the problem is that the image doesn't adjust **at all** with this current code.

When I put `max-width` in place of `width` only the width of the image adjusts while the height does not leaving me with an elliptical and distorted image.

Is there an easy fix to my problem?

Comment: Can someone please tell me why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Setting both `height` and `width` in CSS for an `<img>` is prone to distorting it. If you don't want that to happen, you should just specify one dimension and set the other to `auto`. Considering your image ***is***, in fact, `400px × 400px`, here's what you should use:

```css
#myImg {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 440px) {
  #myImg { 
    width: 90vw;
  }
}

/* optional, for centering */
#myImg {      
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" id="myImg">
```

Play with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/omwf7t6r/). Note I used `440px` so there wouldn't be a jump from `400px` to `360px` when crossing over the `400px` device width limit. You can, of course, use `400px` if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try [object fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/).

```
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  img {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
  }
}
```

Or for better browser compatibility you can also use a background image instead.

Answer (score 0):

For that you'd need to set two `@media` *queries*, one for *horizontal*, and one for *vertical* adjustment, both set to `400px`. With the *horizontal* one, you only use the `width`, and with the *vertical* one, only the `height`:

```css
body {margin: 0}

img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  img {width: 90%}
}

@media (max-height: 400px) {
  img {height: 90vh}
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
```